# C Why is it possible to declare a function with 2D array of variable size (but fixed columns)

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I know that in C one is not allowed to declare 2D arrays with unknown size. For example if I declare `array[][10]` it won't compile. My problem is rather why does it compile when the "array" is declared as the function argument. Example:

```
#define DIM 10

void func(int array[][DIM]){

    //...someting 
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int array[DIM][DIM];

    func(array);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because the compiler needs to know the size of each *element*  of the array(which is an array by itself) to index it correctly. But it doesn't care about their number.

Comment: Ok, but in that case why it does not allow `int array[][DIM];`

Comment: by `int array[][DIM]` i guess your intention is to define the array, declaring it would be `extern int array[][DIM]`. you are trying to make an object in memory out of the 2D array data type and for that what Felix said holds true. by passing it as an argument in the case of array you are passing by reference i.e. you pass only the address of the array that already exists somewhere in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [n1570 (latest draft for C11)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

**§6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes), p7:**

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of *type*’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to
>   *type*’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the
>   array type derivation. [...]

So, the following:

```
void func(int array[][DIM]){
```

is actually just this after adjustment took place:

```
void func(int (*array)[DIM]){
```

This is often called the array *decays as a pointer*. As only a pointer is passed, the compiler doesn't need to know the size of the whole array. But the type information **must** include the size of an element of the array (in this case, the second dimension), so that indexing and pointer arithmetics can work correctly.

---

On the other hand, when you **define** an array, the whole size must be known for (hopefully) obvious reasons: The compiler must reserve the storage space for it.

Comment: Thanks @Felix Palmen. Sorry, but just one more question. But in that case what happens when I make the simple declaration `int array[];`? How the compiler knows which storage space should reserve?

Comment: @duvidasstack a *declaration* doesn't reserve storage space, a *definition* does. In function scope, you can't declare a variable without defining it, so the compiler will just refuse `int array[];` for the missing size. In file scope, such a declaration would be a *tentative definition* and only become a definition if no complete definition is found later. Without a size, `gcc` then assumes the size is `1` -- bottom line: when defining an array, you **have** to give the size.

Answer (score 0):

Function parameters is a special case. Whenever you declare an array as part of a function parameter list, it gets "adjusted" by the compiler to a pointer to the first element. So if you for example declare a function as:

```
void func (int x[5])
```

Then the compiler silently adjusts this in compile time to be the same as:

```
void func (int* x)
```

This language feature is there to make possible to pass an array to a function without making a copy of the whole array on the stack, which would be slow and consume a lot of memory.

Now, this adjustment only works on one level of indirection. When you use a 2D array as part of a function, you get a pointer to the first element. The first element of a 2D array is a 1D array. Therefore you get an *array pointer*, in your case `int (*array)[DIM]`.

And since this adjustment from array to pointer always takes place, it doesn't matter what size the left-most dimension has, because the compiler will translate it to a pointer anyhow. This is why you can type `int array[][DIM]` as a function parameter but never anywhere else.

Would you type `int array[][]` inside the function parameter list however, then you would get a compiler error, because the compiler would adjust this to an array pointer of incomplete type: `int (*)[]`.